# How to start MSSQL Server

Tags: server, 18.04, mssql

I have installed MSSQl Server on my Ubuntu server 18.04 machine and every time I run it, it runs for about 1 min and stops with (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE). This is what shows when I run `systemctl status mssql-server`

```
● mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-05-15 17:43:55 EDT; 2min 20s ago
     Docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux
  Process: 5841 ExecStart=/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 5841 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Tasks: 0
   CGroup: /system.slice/mssql-server.service

May 15 17:43:55 UbuntuServerVaVoose systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 15 17:43:55 UbuntuServerVaVoose systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
May 15 17:43:55 UbuntuServerVaVoose systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
May 15 17:43:55 UbuntuServerVaVoose systemd[1]: Stopped Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
May 15 17:43:55 UbuntuServerVaVoose systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 15 17:43:55 UbuntuServerVaVoose systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 15 17:43:55 UbuntuServerVaVoose systemd[1]: Failed to start Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
```

When I look in the ERRORLOG this is what is displayed.

```
    This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running at Wed May 15 17:24:53 2019
The following diagnostic information is available:

       Reason: 0x00000003
       Status: 0x00000000
      Message: too many nested exceptions
   Stacktrace: 000055f70ed895a4 000055f70ed89116 000055f70ecc300e
               000055f70eda528a 00007fbf48a35890
      Process: 3631 - sqlservr
       Thread: 3635 (application thread 0x4)
  Instance Id: 61c53139-67ac-4e93-92b8-fd14e193d68b
     Crash Id: e4b93b8f-48e0-4683-928c-2cb6ca45426c
  Build stamp: 53ceecd604098a2abee47183edbd7d4bc6065630a4d5742b04eef3004f6a7775
 Distribution: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
   Processors: 2
 Total Memory: 3674222592 bytes
    Timestamp: Wed May 15 17:24:53 2019
```

I see that the message is "too many nested exceptions" but I'm not sure what that means. 
I'm looking for any help on what could be the issue and how to successfully run the server. Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Any solution ? Same Ubuntu 18.04 and SQL 2019

Comment: If I remember correctly the reason that I was not able to get it to work was that my system was too old and didn't have enough or fast enough memory, as the system was a Pentium with ddr2 RAM. I remember switching the hard drive with the install on it over to a newer machine with more memory and a better processor and it worked.